# Performance Impact of creating a view to a Linked SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, view, linked-server

I have a database where I would like to create a view from a linked SQL Server.  Are there performance hits even though this is a view, and are there any maintainability of scalability issues, or something else negative about this approach?  I don't want to duplicate data across databases.

Comment: You mean from a linked **SQL SERVER**, not DB right?

Comment: Updated it to say SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a performance hit for any linked server.
Creating a view will not make this better or worse.
The crucial thing to remember is that ALL data is dragged across the network before any filtering or joining is done.

http://www.sqlusa.com/articles2005/linkedserver/